# How to find a durable lock mount?

Tags: mountain-bike, accessories, lock

I've had one Kryptonite D-lock for the last two years, and it's worked great. I typically don't ride with a pack, so I've used lock mounts ([this kind](http://www.rei.com/product/855205/kryptonite-transit-flexframe-u-lock-bracket?preferredSku=8552050001&cm_mmc=cse_froogle-_-pla-_-product-_-8552050001&mr%3areferralID=2db3e0a6-d20f-11e2-a969-001b2166c2c0)) to keep it secured to the upright on my bike.

However, the lock mounts keep breaking from use after a few months: either the plastic shears off, the "lock-in-place" toggle gets stuck open, the strap breaks, or the tensioner screw's head snaps off some day when I'm trying to wrestle my lock out of the mount.

What kinds of lock mount exist that are durable? If none exists, how would you suggest rigging some mounting solution by hand?

I'm tired of buying new lock mounts, and don't like to lock around the frame of my bike: doing that over the long term has destroyed the paint on the bottom of my Y-brace and rattles around in my knees while I ride.

Comment: I've hit this problem, too. For now, I just throw my lock in a backpack, but I would love to see a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hipster-ish and affected, but tucked between your belt and your back/hip is actually the most secure & reliable U-lock carrying solution of which I am aware, and is actually much more comfortable than it sounds.  Just push the loop side down in between your belt loops, and the lock bar will prevent it falling through if you just cinch your belt up a little bit.  It's a quick and easy solution that won't wear out until your belt does.

Comment: Fabric Horse makes a belt specifically for this, with a strap built in. Still pretty hipster-ish http://fabrichorse.com/lock-holsters.html